# google analytics API revenue metric gives 0 for past dates

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

we use Google analytics API to get metrics in relation to Adsense revenues clicks dates geo location etc...

we make request in every 20 min and we get the data back all right, we do run a double check request 2 days backwards to get a as a sort of finalized assured data.

We have been using this system without any problem for over half a year

Since the beginning of February however we noticed that we get all the data correctly for the given day but when we try to do a refresh for any past date ( ie for yesterday) the clicks and earnings go to 0.00

Has anyone else had any similar problem? was there an update recently we are struggling to find solution for 2 weeks now and seem to have stuck miserable...

Anyone any suggestion ?
Any help?

Does google have any online support or number to call ?

Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: Yes there have been some changes to adsence  recently.  Not sure if this effects you.  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/changelog  If you have a professional account you can contact your account manager.   Other wise there is no other support but here.

Comment: how do I know if I have professional account? where to sign up to it?

Comment: You would know its not cheep https://www.google.com/analytics/360-suite/#?modal_active=none   I sugest you post some code simple example I set this got this data back then two days later the data is this.